# MongooseError: Operation `collections.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do i fix this error i am not using MongoDb Atalas i want to use it in my local machine

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDb'

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))
  mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`)
  });

const NewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    age:Number
})
const newModel = new mongoose.model("collection",NewSchema)

const data = newModel({
    name:"prajwal",
    age:30
})
data.save()

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("listening to the port 3000")
})
```

[image]

This is the error that i got from the code

Comment: Is `mongod` running?

Comment: yes, mongod is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `save()` call should be `await`ed. Also, looks like you are not connected to the DB, try with:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDb';

const NewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});
const newModel = new mongoose.model('collection', NewSchema);

(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(url, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log('DB Connected');

    const data = newModel({
      name: 'prajwal',
      age: 30,
    });
    await data.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
  }
})();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening to the port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Getting this error listening to the port 3000
DB connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Comment: @kick Ok, are you sure that you are running a MongoDB instance locally? If so, try to change the `url` to `'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDb'`

Comment: It worked once I started the instance, thank you @lpizzinidev.